# Can you clone an Android OS Image?

Tags: android, operating-system

We have to set up a number of android devices for a project we are working on... What we have to do is actually edit the iptables of the device.  Rather then doing each one by one I'm curious if there is a way to set up one device then clone the image so that we have an exact replica of that image?

We would then perhaps use PhonixCard to reinstall that image on all of the other devices...

Not sure it matters much but the device is running 4.0.1... all of the devices that we want to replicate the image on are exactly the same device.

Comment: so its the exact same hardware on each device?

Comment: Yes... Exactly the same hardware.

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate of http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22631/clone-android-device but since that is a different stack exchange site it should simply be closed as off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a previous SO answer:

Make a nandroid backup from recovery.
Make sure that the backup is located on the sdcard.
Mount the sdcard on a computer and copy it's contents to a folder on a pc.
Copy the entire contents of the folder you made above to the target device.
Root the device than install a custom recovery if you didn't do this already.
In recovery restore the nandroid backup.
Reboot the device. Now everything should be exactly the same as on the original.
Repeat steps 4-7 for every device.

If there're lots of small files that need to be transferred, another possibility is zip them up copy to the phone and than unzip it using
adb shell unzip path/to/file.zip
Once the command is launched you can disconnect the device the process will continue as long as there're no conflicting files or folders.

[So answer cloning android OS images](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22631/clone-android-device)